# Why subqueried function does not insert new rows?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need a function to insert rows because one column's (`seriano`) default value should be the same as PK `id`.

I have defined table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE some_table_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE some_table
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('some_table_id_seq'::regclass),
    itemid integer NOT NULL,
    serialno bigint,
    CONSTRAINT stockitem_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT stockitem_serialno_key UNIQUE (serialno)
);
```

and function to insert count of rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_item(itemid int, count int DEFAULT 1) RETURNS SETOF bigint AS
$func$
DECLARE 
  ids bigint[] DEFAULT '{}';
  id bigint;
BEGIN
  FOR counter IN 1..count LOOP
    id :=  NEXTVAL( 'some_table_id_seq' );
    INSERT INTO some_table (id, itemid, serialno) VALUES (id, itemid, id);
    ids := array_append(ids, id);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN QUERY SELECT unnest(ids); 
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And inserting with it works fine:

```
$ select insert_item(123, 10);
 insert_item
-------------
           1
           2
           3
           4
           5
           6
           7
           8
           9
          10
(10 rows)

$ select * from some_table;
 id | itemid | serialno 
----+--------+----------
  1 |    123 |        1
  2 |    123 |        2
  3 |    123 |        3
  4 |    123 |        4
  5 |    123 |        5
  6 |    123 |        6
  7 |    123 |        7
  8 |    123 |        8
  9 |    123 |        9
 10 |    123 |       10
(10 rows)
```

But if I want to use function `insert_item` as subquery, it seems not to work anymore:

```
$ select id, itemid from some_table where id in (select insert_item(123, 10));
 id | itemid 
----+--------
(0 rows)
```

I created dumb function `insert_dumb` to test in a subquery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_dumb(itemid int, count int DEFAULT 1) RETURNS SETOF bigint AS
$func$
DECLARE 
  ids bigint[] DEFAULT '{}';
BEGIN
  FOR counter IN 1..count LOOP
    ids := array_append(ids, counter::bigint);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN QUERY SELECT unnest(ids); 
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and this works in a subquery as expected:

```
$ select id, itemid from some_table where id in (select insert_dumb(123, 10));
 id | itemid 
----+--------
  1 |    123
  2 |    123
  3 |    123
  4 |    123
  5 |    123
  6 |    123
  7 |    123
  8 |    123
  9 |    123
 10 |    123
(10 rows)
```

Why does `insert_item` function not insert new rows when called as subquery? I tried to add `raise notice` to the loop and it runs as expected shouting new `id` every time (and increasing the sequence), but no new rows are appended to the table.

I made all the setup available as [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f5763d5a0bf78734ba039ca42e2aa095)

I am using Postgres 11 on Ubuntu.

**EDIT**

Of course, I let out my real reason, and it pays off...

I need the `insert_item` function returning `id`s, so I could use it in `update`-statement, like:

```
update some_table set some_text = 'x' where id in (select insert_item(123, 10);)
```

And addition to the why-question: it is understandable I can get no ids in return (because they share the same snapshot), but the function runs all the needed INSERTs **without** affecting the table. Shouldn't those rows be available in the next query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you mean subqueried insert_item, then `select *` does not change anything for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the subquery and the surrounding query share the same snapshot, that is, they see the same state of the database. Hence the outer query cannot see the rows inserted by the inner query.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (which explains that in the context of `WITH`, although it also applies here):

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables.

In addition, there is a second problem with your approach: if you run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` on your statement, you will find that the subquery is not executed at all! Since the table is empty, there is no `id`, and running the subquery is not necessary to calculate the (empty) result.

You will have to run that in two different statements. Or, better, do it in a different fashion: updating a row that you just inserted is unnecessarily wasteful.

Comment: Shouldn't those rows (inserted in subquery) be available in the next queries?

Comment: Yes, definitely. They are visible in the next statement, but not in the same statement.

Comment: But they are not, cloned another fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1ed4db39283d327af251b23132b25ffe

Comment: I see your other problem. I have added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Laurenz explained the visibility problem, but you don't need the sub-query at all if you re-write your function to return the actual table, rather than just he IDs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_item(itemid int, count int DEFAULT 1) 
  RETURNS setof some_table
AS
$func$
  INSERT INTO some_table (id, itemid, serialno) 
  select NEXTVAL( 'some_table_id_seq' ), itemid, currval('some_table_id_seq')
  from generate_series(1,count)
  returning *;
$func$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select id, itemid 
from insert_item(123, 10);
```

And you get the complete inserted rows.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=96a44434dc7f42832e79843c8d96e2ce)

Comment: Sorry, I left the actual purpose out of question. I made an edit to include reasoning.

Comment: You can still use this function. By why update the rows you have just inserted? Why not just insert them with the correct values

Comment: Before your example I was not sure how to refer to the current PK in the same insert statement. `currval` seems like a solution.